# What will be the output of my recursive function in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, combinations

Consider the following recursive C function that takes two arguments.

```
unsigned int foo(unsigned int n, unsigned int r)
{ 
     if (n > 0)
         return (n % r) + foo(n / r, r); 
     else 
         return 0; 
}
```

> What is value of function foo when it called as foo(512,2)?

Comment: Compile, run and see!

Comment: Try compiling it and running it. What does it say?

Comment: I executed the program and got the output as 2. But how does the execution happens in recursive call?

Comment: no It is 1. see my answer.

Comment: man, you let my reputation up and down... what a disappoint thing to lose the select.

Comment: Yeah ,  This let feel all work worth .

Comment: @user87267867 You are weclome :)

Comment: Your program adds together all the digits in a number with base r. For binary you get the number of set bits. foo(3, 2) is 2 and foo(511,2) is 9. Every 2^x will be 1,as 512.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ,actually is a recursion.

follow the return happened:

```
If n == 0; return 0;

If n == 1; return 1+foo(0,2)

If n == 2; return 0 + foo(1,2);

If n == 4; return 0 + foo(2,2);

  ...

if n == 2^n  return 0 + foo(0+foo(z^n-1,2));


....


So foo(512,2) == foo (2^n,2) == 0+f(1,2) == 1 +f(0,2) = 1;
```

**It return 1.**

Answer (score 0):

Your result is going to be 1. Here is what happens:

1. First call: n = 512, r = 2, n % r = 0; calls `foo (256, 2)`
2. Second call: n = 256, r= 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (128, 2)`
3. Third call: n = 128, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (64, 2)`
4. Fourth call: n = 64, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (32, 2)`
5. Fifth call: n = 32, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (16, 2)`
6. Sixth call: n = 16, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (8, 2)`
7. Seventh call: n = 8, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (4, 2)`
8. Eighth call: n = 4, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (2, 2)`
9. Ninth call: n = 2, r = 2, n % r =  0; calls `foo (1, 2)`
10. Tenth call: n = 1, r = 2, n % r =  1; calls `foo (0, 2)`
11. Eleventh call: n = 0, r = 2; returns 0
12. Tenth call returns 1 + 0 = 1
13. Ninth call and subsequent calls all return 0 + 1 = 1

Unwinding is complete and the function returns 1.